# Target only iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to target your app for only the iPhone 3G model? I have an app that doesn't work with the new echo suppression system introduced with 3GS and 4 and would like to target only 3G models.

I was wondering if there is a way. Would using `armv6` in the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most you can do is target 1G and 3G, and exclude higher versions (or at least I don't know how to do better). Given this table:

```
        iPhone 1G:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera      --        --     
        iPhone 3G:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera      --        --     
 iPhone Simulator:  A-GPS,  accelerometer     --        --        --     
       iPhone 3GS:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera   compass,     --      
         iPhone 4:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera,  compass,  gyroscope  
             iPad:  A-GPS,  accelerometer     --     compass,     --     
           iPad 2:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera,  compass,  gyroscope  
    iPod Touch 1G:   --     accelerometer     --        --        --     
    iPod Touch 2G:   --     accelerometer     --        --        --     
    iPod Touch 3G:   --     accelerometer     --        --        --     
    iPod Touch 4G:   --     accelerometer,  camera,     --     gyroscope
```

You have to set `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to require AGPS, camera, no compass, no gyroscope. So the problem becomes telling if the iPhone is 1G or 3G. If the user upgraded to 4.1 you could ask for gamekit, but this excludes 3G users still running iOS 3. ARM is the same, and OpenGL versions may be the same too.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can itemise specific features that you require or wish to exclude (such as a camera, CPU or GPU) but there's no way to exclude particular devices.

In any case, targeting only the 3G would make for a very limited market.